# Preserve Table Casing not working in Knowledge Base GeneXus 16

Tags: c#, genexus

I have a Knowledge Base in GeneXus 16 Upgrade 10 migrated from previous versions of GeneXus. In the preferences of the version, I have "Preserve Table Casing" = True, however the statements are generated with the tables all in upper case.

In [the documentation](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8844,Preserve%20Table%20Casing%20property), it explains that it will take the value False, as it is a migrated KB.
I need GeneXus to generate the sentences as uppercase and lowercase. How can it be done?

Comment: You should be able to switch the preference to "true", and any object built after that should preserve the casing. Unless you were using dataviews to access those tables ?

Comment: With "Preserve Table Casing" in True or False, always generate SQL sentences with table name in UPPERCASE.  We are generating for Oracle.  It seems that the property value is being ignored.

Comment: I tried with gx 16u8 (Oracle) and its working for me.  If you have a config.gx file check that you have not overridden that preference.

Comment: I don't have a config.gx file.

Comment: I don't know then, but would suggest to make a copy of the KB and test it with GX17, to check whether there is some bug still around.

Comment: I already tried with GeneXus Beta without  luck.

1) Preserve Table Casing = True
2) Create Database
3) Table DiarioDestinatarioAdjuntos in GX

in script

CREATE TABLE DIARIODESTINATARIOADJUNTOS (
  DD_IDDestinatario     NUMERIC(8)    NOT NULL,......

Answer (score 1):

Property "Preserve Table Casing" could be set at Version level and/or at Environment level. You should set it at Environment level

Note: in future Genexus versions this property will be removed from Version level: https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=50878

Comment: I had to change the default value (which was True) to Forced True and it worked fine there. Thanks!